# Laptop Touchpad and Keyboard are Lagging - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, touchpad, asus

Very recently my laptop's keyboard and mouse have started malfunctioning. With the mouse, the cursor will frequently lag when I move it around. With the keyboard, it wont type in a character I pressed at random moments. I checked and noticed that I get the same issue when I run Windows. Furthermore, I **don't** experience these issues when I plug in and use a USB keyboard and mouse.

I've installed all the updates on my Ubuntu system in the hopes that it would fix the issue, but it did not. If someone could offer some suggestions that would be great.

Comment: Same issue on Windows?  Then seems unlikely this is an Ubuntu issue.

Comment: Over the last couple of days I also noticed the occasional 5 to 10 second lag in my laptop using my wireless USB keyboard. The battery is fully charged. Ubuntu 16.04 on daily update cycle. It's probably a new bug.

Comment: @StephenRauch I agree, but I didn't really know what other Stack Exchange site to post this question on, and since I'm at a loss, I figured I would post this here in the hopes that I might get some insight. If I figure it out, I'll come back and post an answer.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I haven't experienced lag for that long. For me, it's the built in keyboard and touchpad that cause the issue. My USB connected keyboard and mouse work fine, as far as I can tell.